# How to create a secure git repository in the cloud?

Tags: git, security, encryption, cloud

I would like to create a git repository and keep a backup copy of it in the cloud. Creating a remote repository would be a simple solution, but the code would be open to anyone with access to the cloud machine, thus compromised. Currently I manage this git repository in the local computer (it is for only one user), them I compress the whole repository, them encrypt the tar ball, them I copy it to a cloud server. This solution is obviously cumbersome to manage, needs to have always the entire repository compressed, encrypted them uploaded/downloaded and it is virtually impossible to work in parallel (although I haven't done this yet). Could someone propose a better solution?

Comment: Make the cloud repo owned 0700 by a `git` user accessible only via ssh and keep the private key to yourself.

Comment: This is good, but still allows that someone in the remote server who has root access to read the repository contents.

Comment: Then you probably want to look into `git bundle`

Comment: Don't zip the repo, just sync it using a tool like BoxCryptor which performs transparent encryption before uploading the changed files/blocks to a cloud storage account.

Comment: git bundle would help to set a exchangeable file, but the solution of BoxCryptor looks closer to what I need. Do you know an open source equivalent of it?

Comment: Can you use Mega? They don't know your encryption keys and have a free plan. https://mega.co.nz/

Comment: That's a good idea too. I read the brochure, but I'm still not quite sure about their claims about safety. Is the code of their client open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several opensource encryption tools solving the task.

- [Git-encrypt](https://github.com/shadowhand/git-encrypt)
- [Git-crypt](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I was looking for! I will take my time to read the scripts and see what does it actually do.

Comment: I've added one more tool, have a look.

Comment: Nice! I will take my time to look their codes to see what they do under the hood.